# findViewById from a different class

Tags: java, android

This should be simple, but even reading other solutions I can't get it...
I simply want to access a TextView with findViewById from a different class (it's in a different file), how to do that?

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView label0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label0);
    MyDialog d = new MyDialog(this);

    public MainActivity(){

    }

    //other methods and stuff...
}
```

Here is the **DialogFragment** that must access the TextView:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private Activity MainActivity;
    private TextView label0;

    public MyDialog(Activity parent) {
    this.MainActivity = parent;
    }

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.alert_content)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

               //here it is, trying to access label0. This is one of the many tries
               label0 = MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.label0);

               //do other stuff...
}
```

I also read many times to never make the views "public static", Is that right?

Comment: Why don't you simply call `parent.findViewById()`?

Comment: Fragments should have no arg constructors. You can use `getActivity().findViewById()` Also why do you have constructor for activity.

Comment: @Raffaele: parent cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Raghunandan: already tried, doesn't work.

Comment: `activity.findViewById()` wont work just like that. try what I have suggested below.

Comment: @glass the fragment can access the Activity instance with getActivity() and easily perform tasks such as find a view in the activity layout. Read communicating with activity @ http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. Also what you are doing is totally worng  `private TextView label0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label0);`. Before layout is set to the activity you are trying to initialize view by using findVIewById. I suggest you go through some tutorial or read the docs again

Comment: @glass you also remove the constructor for both activity and fragment and read the docs

Comment: @Raghunandan: and now it works.... wtf I used getActivity() many times and there always was something wrong, I wonder what was it. Thanks sir, put your answer below if you'd like me to accept it.

Comment: @glass posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no need for constructor for Activity class.
2. Fragments must have no arg constructor
3. The below in Activity is wrong

   `private TextView label0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label0); 
   MyDialog d = new MyDialog(this);`
4. The fragment can access the Activity instance with getActivity() and easily perform tasks such as find a view in the activity layout. Read **Communicating with activity** @ developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

save the textview as a private property of activity and expose it as getters for fragment. Thats the standard way to do it. You will need to cast `fragment.getActivity()` to your activity type and then access the textviewas a getter.

Edit----------------
in the main activity you already have `private TextView label0` just fill its value in `onCreateView`. Then provide a getter method in your activity to access this textView from outside the activity.

```
public TextView getLabelTextView(){
    return this.label0;
}
```

Now in your fragment do something like this:

```
Activity activity = this.getActivity();
MainActivity myActivity = (MainActivity)activity;
TextView tv = myMactivity.getLabelTextView();
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: I already tried, but It doesn't work. How should I do it?
Also, fragment.getActivity() isn't to get the Activity of fragment? Why should I do that if I need a view that is in the other activity?

Comment: Am not sure what you mean by 'didnt work' I use the same ideology in all m android apps and they work just fine. See edit in main answer.